Is there a way specify a custom config and merge it with the default config files in OpenTelementry collector running as a docker image
I am running the Splunk Otel collector as a docker image. I just want to add some custom attributes to be used as tags for my metrics. Is there a simple way to add some attributes?
processors:
  attributes/namespace:
    actions:
      - key: namespace
        value: theNameSpace
        action: upsert

I tried to use the --config argument to specify a custom config and have it merge the values with the default configs. When I add my custom config file with the --config, it complains that "no receiver configuration specified in config" obviously not merging it with the default. I can specify multiple --config arguments but the /etc/otel/collector directory contains multiple config files and it doesn't seem correct to specify all of them on the command line.
It seems like I'm missing a simple way to do this.
